# How to reduce span to necessary size after wrap

Tags: html, css

I have three `<span>`s in a fixed-size `<div>`, where the middle span will sometimes wrap its content into a second line. If the text doesn't break, the contents will usually not fill the whole `<div>`. Thus, the black background in the code below is visible.

However, if the middle `<span>` wraps, it will stretch to the maximum possible size leaving a large gap between its content and the content of the third span.

Manually inserting a `<br/>` resolves this issue but is not convenient, because the fixed-width of the `<div>` might change.

Is it possible to reproduce this behaviour with CSS?

---

Code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kvrjcm2g/):

```css
.background {
  width: 300px;
  background: #000;
}

.sup {
  display: table;
}

.s {
  display: table-cell;
}

.s1 {
  background: #f0f;
}

.s2 {
  background: #ff0;
}

.s3 {
  background: #0ff;
}
```

```html
<!-- implemented behaviour -->
<div class="background">
  <div class="sup">
    <span class="s s1">Starttext</span>
    <span class="s s2">A text which can break because it is long.</span>
    <span class="s s3">Endtext</span>
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
<!-- wanted behaviour -->
<div class="background">
  <div class="sup">
    <span class="s s1">Starttext</span>
    <span class="s s2">A text which can break<br/> because it is long.</span>
    <span class="s s3">Endtext</span>
  </div>
</div>
```